# Htaccess issues

Tags: .htaccess

This is my current htaccess script

```
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE 
 RewriteRule .* - [F]

 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

 RewriteRule ^home$ /index.php?hook=home [NC]
```

But there's a problem when I'm adding $_GET variable, for example:

www.domain.com/home&showPoll=1

OUTPUT:

> ```
> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /home&showPoll=1 was not found on this server.
> ```

Is there a way to fix it ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`www.domain.com/home&showPoll=1` isn't a GET variable because you are missing the `?`. Normally you can just include a `QSA` to include the existing query string:

```
RewriteRule ^home$ /index.php?hook=home [NC,QSA]
```

But if your URL literally is missing the `?` then you can try to parse that part out with a grouping:

```
RewriteRule ^home&?(.*)$ /index.php?hook=home&$1 [NC]
```